# How to hide sidebar in bootstrap by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a great reference here as a side-bar for Bootstrap in designing web form applications:
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

and here's its code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

How do I hide the side-bar navigation first using jquery when the page loads up and only show the side-bar when the button is click "Toggle Menu". The sidebar in this code is showed when the page loads up.

Here is the jquery function for toggle:

```
<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Defaulty add class toggled to sidebar-wrapper div.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

to

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
```

which means you are telling the sidebar to be hidden by default.

---

**Output:**

***View in full screen***

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper" class="toggled">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
          <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
            <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens,
              the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
            <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When the page done loadingyou need toggle the side bar

Jquery support it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggle");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Initially Add toggled class to the sidebar-wrapper. So that initially it will be in hidden state. When you click on menu-toggle it works as usual.

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="toggled">
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this one

Html Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="colPush" class="span0"></div>
    <div id="colMain" class="span12">
        <a id="trig" class="btn btn-inverse">Sidebar Toggle</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.row div {
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
}

.span0 {
    width: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#colPush {
    background-color: #A6BFBA;
}

#colMain {
    background-color: #DE4124;
}

#trig {
    margin: 50px;
}

.row div + div {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

jQuery code :

```
$('#trig').on('click', function () {
    $('#colMain').toggleClass('span12 span9');
    $('#colPush').toggleClass('span0 span3');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/x8S2q/534/)

[create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3](http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/)