# How to hide SideBar Bootstrap when the screen reaches 660px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I'm trying to hide Bootstrap's SideBar when I zoom in. "@media only screen and (max-width: 660px)" but the result is that it is automatically deployed, I do not want that to happen.

Este es el código de bootstrap:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:660px) {
#header {
    height: 160px
}

    #header .brand {
        width: 100%
    }

    #header .user-nav ul {
        padding-left: 0
    }

    #header .toggle-navigation.toggle-left {
        float: left
    }

.sidebar {
    margin-left: -240px
}

.sidebar-toggle {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%
}



.main-content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0
}

.main-content-toggle-left {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.sidebarRight {
    top: 160px;
    width: 100%
}

.user-nav ul li {
    font-size: 12px
}


}
```

[this is my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQo8M.jpg)

Comment: Please do never, under any circumstances, post code as an image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide sidebar in bootstrap by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324321/how-to-hide-sidebar-in-bootstrap-by-default)

Comment: I would suggest creating a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to showcase your issue.

Comment: Hi Toweter thanks for the suggestion, by the way  isnt a duplicate because to hide the default Sidebar I just had to put the class "sidebar-toggle": <nav class = "sidebar sidebar sidebar-toggle"> and my content add the class "main-content-toogle-left" : <section class = "main-content-wrapper main-content-toggle-left">.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a new Class and insert 
    visibility: hidden;

```
@media(max-width: 660px){
  .hide{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}


<nav class="sidebar sidebar sidebar-toggle hide">
```